# QGIS Server Accesing wms/wfs layers using user/pass

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs, qgis-server

I have seen that there is an authentication system in QGIS which, after reading it two times, I don't understand very well:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/es/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_overview.html

I am trying to publish in QGIS Server some postgis layers but they have to be accesible only using a user/pass. I think that what I am reading in that article has nothing to do with what I am trying to achieve.

Is this possible using QGIS Server/Client architecture?

Answer (score 3):

I think [this mail thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Authentication-in-QGIS-Server-WFS-Service-td5080742.html) answers part of your question.

It looks like if you want to protect your Services, you have to do it on the request side, out of QGis itself.

If I understand it correctly, the documentation you link to is about securing the QGis server itself, not the services that you create with it.

EDIT : 
[This library](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client) also mentions using Apache for security, so it looks like the standard indeed.

Comment: The link is not accessible anyomre.